# Do I still need to use break after I use return in switch/case?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, return

```js
switch (input) {
  case 1: 
    return "this is one";
    break;
    
  default:
    break;
}
```

can `return` break the code?
Or it does what break does after return the result?

Comment: No, you don't need break after return, technically anything after return is unreachable code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`return` terminates your function, so the code won't continue executing (and potentially falling through to the next `case` block). There's no point in using `break` in such a situation.